# iOS GCDAsynchsocket opening multiple connections

Tags: ios, tcp, gcdasyncsocket

I am using GCDAsynchronousSocket in iOS to write/read data from a socket. For every 1 second I read/write this data. At the same time I want another connection to be established to read/write a different data on the same port. How do I do this? Is it correct to create a new GCDAsynchronousSocket Object?. Kindly help me with a solution.